# Adonis: How do I seed only a specific file?

Tags: adonis.js

Is there a way to seed only a specific file with the command `adonis seed`? It would be useful especially on production when we add a new seeder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I should have run `adonis seed --help`. Here is how to do it in production.

```bash
node ace db:seed --files "./database/seeders/User.ts"
```